# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu Server as psa-imp won't uninstall

Tags: 10.04, server, apt, package-management, dpkg

When I try to upgrade Ubuntu using

```
apt-get upgrade
```

I get the message

```
(Reading database ... 67729 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing psa-imp ...
```

Where it will hang for ages before spilling out a loads of errors saying that it cannot connect to database:

```
dpkg action:
 Trying to start service mysql... /usr/sbin/mysqld (pid 15949) is running...
done
 Trying to establish test connection... ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
....
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
failed

ERROR while trying to establish test connection
Check the error reason(see log file: /tmp/plesk_10.3.0_installation.log), fix and try again


establish test connection

***** installing problem report *****
ERROR while trying to establish test connection
Check the error reason(see log file: /tmp/plesk_10.3.0_installation.log), fix and try again
establish test connection
dpkg: error processing psa-imp (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 psa-imp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have read the file "/tmp/plesk_10.3.0_installation.log" an it does not give any clues as to why the process failed all it shows is details of the actions taken none of which fail.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed ! See link below that helped me figure this:

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=75882

Seems that the password in the shadow file at /etc/psa/.psa.shadow did not match the password for user 'admin'.